# Blank checkout page when adding a custom checkout field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In WooCommerce checkout page, I'm adding a custom field and everything works fine if I use `woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form` hook or `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` hook.

The problem is that I need the field to be above the `Billing Details` title but when I use `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details` hook **everything disappears** (even the sidebar payment panel), only my custom field title is visible.

My code:

```
// Create Custom checkout Field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'create_custom_field');

function create_custom_field($checkout) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($cart as $key => $value)
    {               
        $bespoke = $woocommerce->cart->get_item_data($value);
        if (strpos($bespoke, 'yes') !== false) {

            echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Bespoke Details') . '</h3>';
            woocommerce_form_field('bespoke_field', array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'class' => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                'label' => __('Tell us about your idea') ,
                'placeholder' => __('Please explain what you want as detailed as possible...') ,
                'required' => true,),
            $checkout->get_value('bespoke_field'));
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Your guidance is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$checkout doesn't exist for this hook, and then it's not defined. So It makes a blank page (an error). But you can use `WC()->checkout` as replacement.

The `WC_cart` method `get_item_data()` is deprecated and [`wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data.html#2858-2930) function replace it since Woocommerce version 3.3.

Also `global $woocommerce` and `$woocommerce->cart` are now replaced with simply `WC()->cart`.

Try this instead:

```
// Add a Custom checkout Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'add_custom_checkout_field' );
function add_custom_checkout_field() {

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $bespoke = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );

        if ( strpos($bespoke, 'yes') !== false ) {

            echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field">';

            echo '<h3>' . __('Bespoke Details') . '</h3>';

            woocommerce_form_field('bespoke_field', array(
                'type'        => 'textarea',
                'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                'label'       => __( "Tell us about your idea", "woocommerce" ),
                'placeholder' => __( "Please explain what you want as detailed as possible...", "woocommerce" ),
                'required'    => true,
            ), WC()->checkout->get_value('bespoke_field') );

            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Amazing @LoicTheAztec! That worked perfect. Thank you so much!